# SQL query for total sales by each department for each day not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is hopefully pretty simple. What I am looking for is **total sales by department for each day.** There are multiple departments, in multiple stores with multiple dates.

What I am getting is a row for each sale in the department. I figure this is because SQL is doing what its told, and showing me a row for each sale because of the transaction time. I am trying to group by each day and I am sure I am missing something simple.

Here is a sample table

```
SalesTotal | Department | StoreNumber | SalesDateTime 
---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------------------- 
3.96         Books        5000         2016-10-01 10:01:11    
0.99         Books        5000         2016-10-01 10:03:40    
3.98         Books        5000         2016-10-01 10:19:45    
0.99         Books        5000         2016-10-01 10:27:58    
2.98         Women        5000         2016-10-01 11:50:11    
1.49         Women        5000         2016-10-01 11:58:35    
2.97         Women        5000         2016-10-01 12:05:11    
4.15         Women        5000         2016-10-01 12:06:20    
3.98         Mens         5000         2016-10-01 12:55:03    
4.98         Mens         5000         2016-10-01 13:02:13    
4.47         Mens         5000         2016-10-01 13:19:40
```

What I am expecting is this

```
SalesTotal | Department | StoreNumber | SalesDateTime 
---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------------------- 
9.93         Books        5000         2016-10-01 
11.58        Womens       5000         2016-10-01
13.43        Mens         5000         2016-10-01
```

I am thinking this is just a SUM and grouping query, but I can't get it to come out that way. I am taking data from a table and putting it into a temp table because I have other data (like the storename, etc) from other tables, but the values above are accurate. Below is the query (yes, i have a couple of variables, but only for selection of dates on the frontend)...

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS SalesTotal
    , Department
    , StoreNumber
    , SaleDateTime
INTO #tblSales
FROM LineItem
WHERE SaleDateTime  BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY  Department,  T.StoreNumber, SaleDateTime

SELECT *
FROM #tblSales
```

Thanks for taking a look, if more information is needed, let me know. As noted, I can't seem to figure out what I am missing as to the grouping part. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping by date *and* time, meaning if they are not identical, they will not be grouped. To group based on only date, you'll have to convert `TransactionDateTime` to a `Date`, and do your selection/grouping on that instead.

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS SalesTotal
    , Department
    , StoreNumber
    , CONVERT(date, SaleDateTime) As SaleDate
INTO #tblSales
FROM LineItem
WHERE SaleDateTime  BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY  Department,  T.StoreNumber, CONVERT(date, SaleDateTime)

SELECT *
FROM #tblSales
```

You're supplying slightly conflicting information, being that your query is using a field called `SaleDateTime`, yet your example table uses `TransactionDateTime`. The example above uses `SaleDateTime`.

Comment: ....and there it was staring at me in the face. I totally understand it now. Thank you for your input. Answer marked.

Curiosity question if you do not mind. I changed my query to do the summing and conversion during the SELECT FROM the temp table. Will the performance be better if I use the SELECT INTO to do the conversion and sums?

Comment: Truthfully, I don't have a great answer for you. I would honestly just do a comparison of the two and see which yields you quicker return speeds! Good luck.

Comment: Using the SELECT INTO resulted in a difference of 4 seconds quicker.

Comment: Like I said... `SELECT INTO` is quicker for sure ;) haha. Good to know, thanks for reporting back!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are grouping using the time in the date as well and they differ so unless if rows have the same exact time in them, it will fail to group as you need it to. Try this instead:

```
select sum(Price) as SalesTotal,
    Department,
    StoreNumber,
    min(convert(varchar, SaleDateTime, 102)) as SaleDateTime
from LineItem
where SaleDateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by Department,
    T.StoreNumber,
    year(SaleDateTime),
    datepart(dy, SaleDateTime)
```

Comment: Thanks Anand for helping!!

Comment: You are welcome and an upvote would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be OK, problems lies with your variable/column names of the query, as i tested your problem with minor changes as you posted data and it works fine, query that i execute is as (Modified) as per your provided data

```
SELECT SUM(SalesTotal), Department, StoreNumber
FROM Test
Where TransactionDateTime = '2016-10-01 10:01:00.000'
GROUP BY  Department,  StoreNumber, TransactionDateTime
```

if problem remains as it, please paste your error/results here